# Constraints involving max in ILP

Tags: constrained-optimization, linear-programming

> Consider $n$ apps and $m$ transactions. $x_{ij}$ is a binary variable, it takes 0 or 1. $x_{ij}$ takes 1 if $i$th app is used for $j$th transaction, else 0.
> min $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij}$
> subject to
> $\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij} \leq 0.25m$
> $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ij}$ = 1
> $\forall i'$ max($x_{i'j}$)=1
> $i'$ = apps through which $j^{th}$ transaction can go through.

Is there any way to represent this in the form of an ILP? I am using PULP to convert this into ILP but I am unable to figure out how to write the max constraint in the solver.

Comment: Could you do something like
for j in range(m):
    problem += pulp.lpSum(x[i][j] for i in range(n)) == 1
to write the max constaint?

Comment: Hint: Use a slack variable.

Comment: I don't see why the max condition doesn't automatically hold. Maybe it is stated wrong?